# Inherit dependencies version from app to library module

Tags: android, android-library

I created a library that uses some standard dependencies inside:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:16.0.0'
}
```

I wonder if is there a way to inherit dependency version from the app, something like:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$INHERITED_FROM_APP'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:$INHERITED_FROM_APP'
}
```

Comment: you can define version in  your app level gradle and try to use them in module level gradle.

Comment: @KaranMer ok, but if I publish library on jitpack for example, and I have only dependency in my app not the module, does it work too?

Comment: at that time it might not work, you can try it first if it works you can add it as user installation guilde .

Comment: just tried, it gives me  `Execution failed for task ':app:myappReleaseJavaWithJavac'`

Comment: upvoted, someone other might be able to have a better look at this.

Answer (score 0):

In your project level `build.gradle`, define global variables

```
buildscript {    
    ext.global_minSdkVersion = 16
    ext.global_targetSdkVersion = 28
    ext.global_buildToolsVersion = '28.0.1'
    ext.global_supportLibVersion = '28.0.0'
    ext.global_googleLibVersion = '16.0.0'
}
```

Go to app level `build.gradle`, and use global variables

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$global_supportLibVersion'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:$global_googleLibVersion'
}
```

Comment: ok, but if I publish library on jitpack for example, and I have only dependency in my app not the module, does it work too?

Answer (score 0):

Quite a convenient solution to define `dependencies.gradle` file with you dependencies:
`dependencies.gradle` file:

```
ext.versions = [
 'supportLib' : 28.0.0,
]

ext.deps = [
  'appcompat': "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${versions.supportLib}",
]
```

`build.gradle` file application level:

```
buildscript {
  apply from: rootProject.file('dependencies.gradle')
  ....
}
```

`build.gradle` file app module level:

```
implementation deps.appcompat
```

Comment: ok, but if I publish library on jitpack for example, and I have only dependency in my app not the module, does it work too?

Comment: Of course. When you publish your library, it is assemble to jar file with all dependencies.